# unresolved external operator delete(void*)

Tags: c++, windows, driver, allocation

I have a piece of c++ code (in Windows driver, but this might be not so important for our discussion) in Visual Studio 2013 update 4

I have this allocator implementation:

```
class allocator {
 public:
 pointer allocate(size_type n, typename allocator<void, TAG>::const_pointer = 0) {
            return static_cast<pointer>(::ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, n*sizeof(value_type), tag()));
        }

        void deallocate(pointer p, size_type) {
            ::ExFreePoolWithTag(p, tag());
        }

        void construct(pointer p, value_type const& val) {
            ::new(p)value_type(val);
        }

        void destroy(pointer p) {
            p->~value_type();
        }
}
```

I have a basic class, that has a defined destructor that causes me compile errors for scenario:

```
    struct A {
        A(int i) : i(i) {
            ::DbgPrint("A::A");
        }

        ~A() {
            ::DbgPrint("A::~A");
        }
        int i;
    }; 

void Allocator_support_works_as_expected() {
    allocator<A> alloc;

    auto p = alloc.allocate(1);
    alloc.construct(p, A(1));

    alloc.destroy(p); // IF i comment this out it compiles, but no destructor called
    alloc.deallocate(p, sizeof(A));
}
```

I get following when trying to compile:

error message:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: void * __cdecl A::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GA@@QEAAPEAXI@Z)
```

In "destroy" implementation I call class destructor, because allocator uses placement new. What's going on ?

**EDIT 1**

It seems that for windows driver development environment I have to define global operator new even if in my case I don't use it

Comment: I have questions about a `void` function with `return 0;`

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you `#include <new>` to make sure that placement-new's overloads of `operator new` and `operator delete` are correctly declared?

Comment: @MooingDuck it's just a snippet sorry

Comment: Snippets should compile.

Comment: @DanielDaranas in theory that should be the case but there seems to be a bug.. If that is the case indeed 

Comment: I think Daniel meant that the goal is to post an example of your problem that will at least compile. The issue you're seeing is that it doesn't link, but you would only see that error after successful compilation.

Comment: @MooingDuck vs 2013 update 4

Comment: These may help, let us know if any tips here work: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/263489-unresolved-c-functions-linking

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm not able right now.. I'll see later. Do you have the original link from microsoft connect with the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there's no stupid mistake such as

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\bin\cl.exe" /EHsc /nologo /W4 test.cpp
```

I accidentally set environment for different version of MSVC and it took me 15 minutes to realize where the problem is